# Run-time cost of dependently-typed programming with GHC

Tags: haskell, optimization, runtime, compile-time, dependent-type

I am programming a dependently-typed library in Haskell. Using profiling on my test executable I see something like:

```
commutativity' Math 1189 4022787186 29.1 27.2 29.1 27.2
```

`commutativity'` is basically (recursive) proof of the integer addition commutativity property for type-level integers. It is defined this:

```
commutativity' :: SNat n -> SNat m -> Plus (S n) m :~: Plus n (S m)
commutativity' SZ m = Refl
commutativity' (SS n) m = gcastWith (commutativity' n m) Refl
```

And then used in my library with `gcastWith` to prove the equivalence of various types.

So... 29% of my runtime is spent on something completely useless, since type-checking happens at compile-time.

I had naively assumed that this wouldn't happen.

Is there something I can do to optimize away these useless calls?

Comment: This is the cost of not using a total language. Type safety rests on evaluating proofs to canonical form. In total languages, proofs can be trusted without evaluation and thus erased at runtime. You could take the trust hit and use `unsafeCoerce`, once you've checked your program gets past the typechecker.

Comment: See section 4.4.4 "Running proofs" of Richard A. Eisenberg's thesis https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07978

Comment: I dream of GHC integrating a termination (abstract) checker, and automatically optimize/rewrite "proofs" using zero-cost coercions. That would be _really_ nice.

Comment: @pigworker I thought partial recursiveness was necessary for Turing completeness?

Comment: @denormal Well, consider that Turing-completeness may not be *that* important... most programs can be written in non-Turing-complete languages. Also, according to [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/23916/7246) you can somehow model partial functions in languages like Idris: my guess is that this is due to the fact that such languages also have codata and productive definitions (i.e. coinduction) which is often not considered, so it seems like termination+coinduction may be Turing-complete (but don't quote me on this).

Comment: @denormal Partiality is not necessary for Turing-completeness, despite popular misconception. Total languages can express infinite processes: they just can't promise the finiteness of infinite processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are *very* sure the proof term terminates you can use something like

```
unsafeProof :: proof -> proof
unsafeProof _ = unsafeCoerce ()

someFunction :: forall n m.  ...
someFunction = case unsafeProof myProof :: Plus (S n) m :~: Plus n (S m) of
   Refl -> ...
```

This must be used only on types having a single no parameters constructor, e.g. `Refl` for `a :~: b`. Otherwise, your program will likely crash or behave weirdly. Caveat emptor!

A safer (but still unsafe!) variant could be

```
unsafeProof :: a :~: b -> a :~: b
unsafeProof _ = unsafeCoerce ()
```

Note that you can still crash the program with that, if you pass bottom to it.

I hope one day GHC will perform this optimization safely and automatically, ensuring termination through static analysis.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess demand for that termination analysis is going to be a lot bigger after Richard Eisenberg implements dependent types.

Comment: FWIW, the idiom I see more often in `base` and other libraries ([example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Typeable.html#eqT)) is `unsafeCoerce Refl`, not `unsafeCoerce ()`. I suppose it's more resilient to a change of representation of `:~:`

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson It clarifies the intent better, yes. For the general case, though, `unsafeProof :: proof -> proof` there is no "best" constructor we can use, so I used `()` as the canonical element of the final type.